# English date format is not proper displayed in Word

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

English dates are written with an ordinal number, e.g., Friday, 17th of April 2020. I am puzzled that in Word the English dates are not shown with an ordinal number (see the date format options from Word). Is there anyway to customize the date format? The ordinal is also not displayed for the UK language.

[image]

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by 'ordinal number'? Do you mean ordinal numeral, like first, second, third etc? Also, which English? US, UK, Canadian, Australian, Indian… all have different rules

Comment: I refer literally to 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc.

Comment: OK, ordinal numeral. tbh I've never noticed it before, but nothing on my machine uses that, Word, Pages etc & the OS itself all just use the integer.

Comment: Friday, 17th of April *of the* 2020 is not an English (S.A., U.S,, G.B or elsewhere I've ever seen.  In LibreOffice Writer, it can be done: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/133846/how-to-get-date-ordinals-in-date-format/

Comment: MS Word? I can't understand your issue. Can you please elaborate? I can write anything in Word, be it ordinal or integer. Can please add more detail?

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik I'm glad that it can be done in LibreOffice. There should be then a way also to do it in MS Office

Comment: @Bhavya Gupta I refer inserting a date with a specific format, which contains the day number 1st, 2nd, 3rd...

Comment: @birdman it can be done in word too. I tried but was quite complicated for me. I recommend starting a bounty.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta, you may answer your own question. It would be useful to others to know how you implemented ordinals! It's a cardinal error that MS makes it difficult.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have uploaded my answer. An upvote would be helpful. Also feel free to share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Macro that does the job.
Step 1 - Go to View Tab.
Step 2 - Click on Macros. A new widows pops up.
Step 3 - Give any name to the macro and click on create. Another window pops up.
Step 4 - Paste the below mentioned code between SUB and END SUB.

```
   Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "TIME  \@ ""dddd, "" ", PreserveFormatting:=True
   Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "TIME  \@ ""d""   \*ordinal ", PreserveFormatting:=True
   Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "TIME  \@ ""' of' MMMM, yyyy"" ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

Now close the window and you are good to go. Click on Macros. Select the macro you created. Click on Run. All this is one-time work-to-do.
Note: Instead of changing tabs to run a Macro, you can add a button in you Quick Access Toolbar or even create a keyboard short-cut!

Comment: Friday, 17th of April 2020 - is not proper. You need a comma right after April there. Friday, 17th of April, 2020

Comment: @Sanu_012 I have a comma in my macro. Please recheck. Did you try in Word?

Comment: Okay, I got it now :)